# Why is Google Assistant responding that it is "unable to reach" my app while the controls work in Google Home app?

Tags: google-smart-home

For just a handful of users, Google Assistant responds to them with "Unable to reach myApp" when they attempt to control a device. However, the Google Home app shows that all of the devices are online, in their proper state, and can be controlled by tapping. If the device is updated through our native app or physically, the Home app properly updates. It **only** breaks when using the Google Assistant - sometimes.

Google Assistant works for the large majority of users. Also, the users who experience this issue can only temporarily fix it by reintegrating our app with their Google account.

The users claim that all of their other integrations work properly and that they only experience this with us.

Comment: Do you see abnormally high latency for these users?

Answer (score 0):

You can try relinking your account to troubleshoot this since the Google Home App is showing every device in its correct state which means account linking and every subsequent step was a success.

Furthermore, my advice would be to include the following flow:
https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/troubleshooting and try to capture error logs for those cases which are causing the issue.